# How can we get value from a custom widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to access value of text from TextBox class to some other dart file, how it can be done?

I have given the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hint;
  final String text;
  TextBox({this.hint});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0,horizontal: 10.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hint,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 10.0),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: (value){
          text=value;
          return text;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function inside the class like:

```
void _didPushButton() {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/newRoute', arguments:<String>{'varName':value});
}
```

varName is the required argument in the other dart file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `state management` into account. At the moment your `TextBox` widget does not hold any state.

There are different approaches to do so, you can check [state management in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) to have an overview.

Generally speaking (the actual implementation highly depends on what you end up choosing), you want to "lift the state up".

Quoting what is also stated in the doc:

```
In Flutter, it makes sense to keep the state above the widgets that use it.
```